# getting and displaying a javascript object by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var pdata = [{ Name: "Apples", Price: 1.99 },{ Name: "Bananas", Price: 2.45 }];

 $('#add1').click(function () {
        var selected = $('#produceList option:selected').index();
```

I have a variable set to an index and I want to get and display the javascript object by the var selected index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class-'item'></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#add1').click(function () {
        var selected = $('#produceList option:selected').index(),
            item = pdata[selected];
        $('.item').html(item.Name + ', ' + item.Price);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/XCbhu/)**

Comment: Ok for this one it is displaying  item.Name+item.Price.

Comment: one more question it returns undefined in IE10 for some reason why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the index, you would just do

`pdata[index];`

so in your example

```
$('#add1').click(function () {
    var index = $('#produceList option:selected').index();
    var selected = pdata[index];
})
```

assuming the code you give in the question gives the index of the selected item.

Comment: ok could you show me some code I want to display the key/value text in my html

Comment: the code is getting the index I have that part down I want to get the text and display it in my html by that index

Answer (score 0):

The pairings are referenced using a simple array index, so your values are:

```
pdata[0] ---> {Name="Apples", Price=1.99}
pdata[1] ---> {Name="Bananas", Price=2.45}
```

To get to the specific attributes of the object, you need to use the name of the attribute, so your values are:

```
pdata[0].Name ---> "Apples"
pdata[0].Price ---> 1.99
pdata[1].Name ---> "Bananas"
pdata[1].Price ---> 2.45
```

So, to access the information that you want, you would use `pdata[index].Name` and   `pdata[index].Price`, once you have retrieved the index.

Comment: this is what is displayed on my html

Comment: Sorry its displaying this    function item() { [native code] }